# How to remove initial null values from case statement?

Tags: sql, null, union, multiple-columns

I have a table (DLVERYDAY) with one column for each day of the week. If a customer have a delivery date assign to a day, then the column of that day is set to 'Y". I want to combine the seven days in just one column, for example "Delivery Day" and if the Sunday column is 'Y' then under Delivery Day will appear "Sunday" for every customer.

I tried working this out with union, but I just can't get what i need.  The first comparison (when comparing with Sunday) always appears NULL.  I don't want null values to appear if that day is not a delivery day or is set to N.

```
dbo.DLVERYDAY

ID        Location Name WH     Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat 

0000000 CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1     DO N   N   Y   N   N   N   Y

0000001 CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2     DO N   Y   N   N   N   Y   N

SELECT CUST_ID, CUSLOC_ID, CUSLOC_NAM, WH, 
(CASE WHEN DAY1 LIKE 'Y' THEN 'Sunday'END) AS  'Delivery Day' 
FROM dbo.DLVERYDAY WHERE CUSLOC_ID = '0000000' OR CUSLOC_ID = '0000001'

UNION 

SELECT CUST_ID, CUSLOC_ID, CUSLOC_NAM, WH, 
(CASE WHEN DAY2 = 'Y' THEN 'MONDAY' END) AS 'Delivery Day'  
FROM dbo.DLVERYDAY WHERE CUSLOC_ID = '0000000' OR CUSLOC_ID = '0000001'

UNION 

SELECT CUST_ID, CUSLOC_ID, CUSLOC_NAM, WH, 
(CASE WHEN DAY3 = 'Y' THEN 'TUESDAY' END) AS 'Delivery Day'
FROM dbo.DLVERYDAY WHERE CUSLOC_ID = '0000000' OR CUSLOC_ID = '0000001'

AND SO ON....
```

Example of two customers with more than one delivery day.

```
Actual Result: 

ID         Location Name  WH    Delivery Day

0000000 CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1   DO    NULL

0000000 CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1   DO    SATURDAY

0000000 CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1   DO    TUESDAY

0000001 CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2   DO    NULL

0000001 CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2   DO    MONDAY

0000001 CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2   DO    THURSDAY
```

```
Expected Result: 

ID        Location Name   WH Delivery Day 

0000000 
CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1       DO Tuesday 

0000000 
CUSTOMER1|LOCATION1       DO Saturday 

0000001 
CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2       DO Monday 

0000001 
CUSTOMER2|LOCATION2       DO Friday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Case Statement you can just use the WHERE Clause. The WHERE clause will filter out the records that would be NULL. Here is an example for Monday and Tuesday, you could repeat and continue to get all 7 Days. That's the simpliest answer to understand.

```
   SELECT CUST_ID
   , CUSLOC_ID
   , CUSLOC_NAM
   , WH
   , 'Monday' AS  'Delivery Day' 
   FROM dbo.DLVERYDAY
   WHERE (CUSLOC_ID = '0000000' OR CUSLOC_ID = '0000001')
      AND Day1 = 'Y'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CUST_ID
   , CUSLOC_ID
   , CUSLOC_NAM
   , WH
   , 'Tuesday' AS  'Delivery Day' 
   FROM dbo.DLVERYDAY
   WHERE (CUSLOC_ID = '0000000' OR CUSLOC_ID = '0000001')
      AND Day2 = 'Y'
```

A more complex solution that may cover SQL subjects that you aren't exposed to yet would be to use the UNPIVOT function.

Here is a [link to an article about the UNPIVOT function](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/). This would help you normalize your data.